# in and out oracle parameters in vb.net result in null errors

Tags: oracle, parameters, null, out

so this code works with just the out parameter but then when you add in parameters weird nulls start showing up and also the straight in parameters work too so it is just when there are both in and out parameters.

the part with problems is the in and out parameters do not want to coexist

```
            cmd.Parameters.Add("PKEY", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In sqlParams
                Dim newParam As New OracleParameter(kvp.Key, OracleDbType.Varchar2, kvp.Value, Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
                newParam.Size = 400
                cmd.Parameters.Add(newParam)
            Next
```

This works

```
Public Shared Sub Run_Oracle_Query(ByVal queryToRun As String, ByVal sqlParams As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Dim dbConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ITSS").ConnectionString
        Dim con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(dbConnString)
        Dim cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = queryToRun
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In sqlParams
                cmd.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)

            Next
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'log all sql queryies very expensive operation
            LogThisString("Log All queries: " & queryToRun, "Always")
        Catch ex As OracleException ' catches only Oracle errors
            OracleExceptionLogging(ex.Number, queryToRun, ex)
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogThisString("General Error SQL: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Always")
            ' MsgBox("Could Not Perform This Database Operation")
        Finally
            con.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This works

```
    Public Shared Function Run_Insert_Oracle_Query_Return_ID(ByVal queryToRun As String, ByVal IDcolumnName As String) As String
        Dim dbConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ITSS").ConnectionString
        Dim con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(dbConnString)
        Dim cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        Dim strUkey As String = ""
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = queryToRun & " RETURNING " & IDcolumnName & " INTO :UKEY"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("PKEY", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            strUkey = cmd.Parameters("PKEY").Value.ToString
            Return strUkey
        Catch ex As OracleException ' catches only Oracle errors
            OracleExceptionLogging(ex.Number, queryToRun, ex)

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogThisString("General Error SQL: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Always")
            PopupMsgBox("Database Error", "Database Integrity Constants Violated SQL Operation Will Not Be Executed")
        Finally
            con.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try

        Return strUkey
    End Function
```

This does not work

```
Public Shared Function Run_Insert_Oracle_Query_Return_ID(ByVal queryToRun As String, ByVal IDcolumnName As String, ByVal sqlParams As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String

        Dim dbConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ITSS").ConnectionString
        Dim con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(dbConnString)
        Dim cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        Dim strUkey As String = ""
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = queryToRun & " RETURNING " & IDcolumnName & " INTO :UKEY"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("PKEY", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In sqlParams
                Dim newParam As New OracleParameter(kvp.Key, OracleDbType.Varchar2, kvp.Value, Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
                newParam.Size = 400
                cmd.Parameters.Add(newParam)
            Next
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            strUkey = cmd.Parameters("PKEY").Value.ToString
            Return strUkey
        Catch ex As OracleException ' catches only Oracle errors
            OracleExceptionLogging(ex.Number, queryToRun, ex)

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogThisString("General Error SQL: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Always")
            PopupMsgBox("Database Error", "Database Integrity Constants Violated SQL Operation Will Not Be Executed")
        Finally
            con.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try

        Return strUkey
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

crap so i guess it does look for order asnd the output does need to be at end like this.....this works solved my own problem

```
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In sqlParams
            Dim newParam As New OracleParameter(kvp.Key, OracleDbType.Varchar2, kvp.Value, Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
            newParam.Size = 400
            cmd.Parameters.Add(newParam)
        Next
cmd.Parameters.Add("PKEY", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
```